# ZF2 - retrieving bottom row id from table

Tags: zend-framework2

I am trying to retrieve the latest entered if from the 'order' table within my database.

I'm currently trying to use the following method:

```
public function getLatestOrderId()
{
        $adapter = $this->adapter;

        $sql = new Sql($adapter);

        $select = $sql->select();
        $select->columns(array('id' => 'orderId'));
        $select->from('order');
        $select->order('orderId DESC');
        $select->limit(1);

        $statement = $sql->prepareStatementForSqlObject($select);
        $statement->execute();
}
```

I have a feeling that this should be working. I am then accessing this method in the controller like so:

```
$orderId = $this->getOrderTable()->getLatestOrderId();
```

I have realised that at present the getLatestOrderId method does not actually return anything e.g. return $statement->execute();. This is because I receive an error saying that the sql result could not be converted to a string.

I'm insure what is going wrong, so any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: It might help if you edit your post and include the actual error message you're getting. As an aside, `order` is a reserved keyword in at least MySql, if you're using that as your rdbms you might want to consider a different table name.

Comment: Agreed. Jamie, can you post the error message and code please?